# Using Table to generate lists that requires more than one line to generate the desired expression

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm struggling to adapt to what I "believe" would be a more Mathematica-esque approach to things from my procedural programming background. Specifically I am struggle to create lists in a clean way that require more than one line to create the expression whose outputs will be the entries.

To try and illustrate, let's suppose we want to create a list of random points in the unit circle and that we'll do this by choosing random points in polar coordinates and then convert them to cartesian coordinates. I feel like the Table function is the cleanest way to make a list in Mathematica, but unless I make an additional function it doesn't seem like there is a good way to go about this. To reiterate, I'd like an approach that uses something like Table but **does not** require creating a function

To illustrate consider the following code

```
 r := RandomReal[{0, 1}];
theta := RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}];
Pts = Table[{r*Cos[theta], r*Sin[theta]}, {i, 1, 100}];
```

This fails to generate random points in the unit circle because r and theta appear twice and thus are not the same within each generated point.

The only work around, still using Table, I can think of involves creating a function but again, I want to avoid this. For example I want to avoid this workaround:

```
GetPt[r_, theta_] := {r*Cos[theta], r*Sin[theta]};
Pts = Table[
   GetPt[RandomReal[{0, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}]], {i, 1, 100}];
```

Admittedly, I think this is a perfectly fine approach, but in the interest of learning flexibility I'm trying to get a sense of all the possible ways to do something.

A for loop will get around this but generating a list with Append does not seem very clean. e.g.

```
Pts = {};
For[i = 0, i < 100, i++,
 r = RandomReal[{0, 1}];
 theta = RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}]; 
 AppendTo[Pts, {r*Cos[theta], r*Sin[theta]}]
 ]
```

Hopefully it makes sense what my question is. Anny suggestions or comments are welcome. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To invoke `r` and `theta` once in every step you can do

```
SeedRandom[1]
Pts1 = Table[{(r1 = r)*Cos[t = theta], r1 Sin[t]}, {i, 1, 100}];
```

or

```
SeedRandom[1]
Pts2 = Table[With[{r1 = r, t = theta}, r1 {Cos[t], Sin[t]}], {i, 1, 100}];
```

Both approaches give the same result when used with same seed:

```
Pts1 == Pts2
```

> True

To get a list with similar structure directly you can use:

```
rlist = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100];
tlist = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, 100];
Pts3 = rlist Transpose[{Cos[tlist], Sin[tlist]}]
```